# organising cucumber features from user requests in the real world

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, pivotaltracker

When I see tutorials regarding cucumber I see feature examples like "manage users" with scenarios such as add users, delete user etc. This all very well when starting a project.

However, I would like to use something like pivotal tracker with third-party tools such as pickler and have features as stories (the pivotal tracker concept) which can be derived from requests and bug reports (as they may be also referred to in other project and code management tools).

The problem I see is that the number of feature files could become quite large because a new one could be started for each request, also the number of scenarios could be low in each because they would be spread over multiple feature files over different periods, so how would you organise them?

also will testing become too slow over time how can this be reduced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read of this: [Features != Stories](http://blog.mattwynne.net/2010/10/22/features-user-stories/)

Comment: I agree which is why I referred to them as a pivotal tracker concept because that's how entries are labelled on the platform, pickler converts these to feature files. But really the concept of "a story" in pivotal tracker is irrelevant because the entry can include any type of data you wish, its just a text box really.